# Sine Wave Converted into Audio on WAW Format

Tags: python, audio, signals

I created two sine signal and ı sumed up these signal. I want to convert the sine signal into the sound for listening. Is it possible in python? As ı researched, the sine waves can be converted in waw to be listen in different audio applications. I have found source code to convert the sine signal but ı got error message. If the my way is true how can ı do that in this method?

I created signal.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

samples = 50
f = 160
x = np.arange(samples)
y1 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f * (x/samples))
plt.figure()
plt.stem(x,y1, 'r')
plt.plot(x,y1)
plt.xlabel('Time -->')
plt.ylabel('<-- Amplitude -->')
plt.show()

samples = 50
f = 188.6
x = np.arange(samples)
y2 = np.sin(2*np.pi*f * (x/samples))
plt.figure()
plt.stem(x,y2, 'r')
plt.plot(x,y2)
plt.xlabel('Time -->')
plt.ylabel('<-- Amplitude -->')
plt.show()

y3 = y1 + y2
plt.plot(x,y3)
plt.xlabel('Time -->')
plt.ylabel('<-- Amplitude -->')
plt.show()
```

I have converted into waw but ı got error

```
import wave
import struct

def signal_to_wav(signal, fname, Fs):
    """Convert a numpy array into a wav file.

     Args
     ----
     signal : 1-D numpy array
         An array containing the audio signal.
     fname : str
         Name of the audio file where the signal will be saved.
     Fs: int
        Sampling rate of the signal.

    """
    data = struct.pack('>' + ('Bdd'*len(signal)), *signal)
    wav_file = wave.open(fname, 'wb')
    wav_file.setnchannels(1)
    wav_file.setsampwidth(2)
    wav_file.setframerate(Fs)
    wav_file.writeframes(data)
    wav_file.close()
```

Here is the error ı got

```
error: required argument is not an intege
```

Comment: How do you call your `signal_to_wav()` function ? The Fs argument must be an integer (sample rate).

Comment: yes ı did it. The actual error line is '''data = struct.pack('>' + ('Bdd'*len(signal)), *signal)'''